# Why the number of poles and zeros for a RHS signal in the Z domain is equal?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, z-transform

I can not understand the reason why the following sentence is true:

> If we have a Right-Hand signal(RHS) x(n), X(z), the Z-transform of x(n), has the same number of poles and zeros except at z = infinity

can any one explain why!?

Comment: http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~fessler/course/451/l/pdf/c3.pdf

Comment: this link may help you